# GitHub GraphQL API Activity info

Tags: api

I could not find information about "activity" in the GitHub v4 GraphQL API. I was looking for something like [GitHub v3 RESTful API - Activity](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/activity).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct equivalent to Activity in the Github GraphQL activity.  You may be able to obtain some of the information you are looking for by querying Repository objects and their members:

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/objects#repository